# How can I figure out which nodeunit is causing async errors more quickly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-modules, async.js

I ran into an issue while testing a fairly large refactor (on this case taking moving an old service from node.js 0.12 to 10.x). We use grunt so I got the following results out of `grunt nodeunit:all`:

```
...
verify-api.routes.test.js
test setValues (pass)
Fatal error: Cannot read property 'setUp' of undefined
```

Some googling leads to a couple threads - [this one](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit/issues/234) is a good synopsis - that correctly show this error is when `test.done` is called multiple times.

Great! No problem. Armed with that you now dig into `verify-api.routes.test.js` where you see/assume that the problem is located based upon the output. Only - you're wrong. It turns out that the error (in my case) is located two test suites *before* `verify-api.routes.test.js` amongst the full suite of tests run. To be fair to nodeunit this is partly grunt's fault as the output is misleading us into identifying `verify-api.routes.test.js`... but as shown at the bottom the other ways simply make it more clear that nodeunit doesn't know where the problem lies - which is only marginally better.

I've found that I run into a problem like this maybe once once in a while - but when it happens it's painful... Situations like this are particularly painful bc they generally manifest only occasionally - e.g. at release time or after a seemingly benign merge.

Is there a fast trick out there that people are using to find these problems or make their code more resilient to these types of issues?

---

As mentioned some nodeunit runners provide different results... more/less misleading depending upon the context:

I got the following output when running nodeunit directly using : `nodeunit tests/**/*.test.js`

```
OK: 162 assertions (2720ms)

FAILURES: Undone tests (or their setups/teardowns): 
- test setValues
```

And this through Intellij's IDEA which nicely gives us a bit more info:

```
./node_modules/nodeunit/lib/core.js:285
    if (group.setUp) {
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setUp' of undefined
    at wrapGroup (./node_modules/nodeunit/lib/core.js:285:15)
    at Object.exports.runSuite (./node_modules/nodeunit/lib/core.js:93:13)
```

Comment: Clarified, and made more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So - I'm looking for best practices that help for this class of issues. Out of self-defense and for those that follow I'll mention a few things that I think are important and then spend some time on the tactics that helped me today...

## 1. Continuous Integration

Running tests as frequently as possible shows you more precisely which change caused the issue. When you have a lot of tests or some long running tests you may find you cannot run them all (as described above) but refactoring the important ones to make them faster. Also running tests by area can help.

## 2. Peer Review / Pair Coding

Is often good for catching issues as they're happening or shortly thereafter saving debug time down the line in terms of debug and maintenance in exchange for a little bit more up front time.

## 3. Use of `async`

If you're async programming you really should look into this library to keep your code just a bit cleaner. Async also has almost magical components that can handle async dependency management, filtering and more. If you're developing node code get (async)[https://github.com/caolan/async] now.

---

Last but not least ... thing that helped me most today was running tests in isolation using `find`:

## 4. Run tests in isolation using `find`

The thing that helped me most today was running tests in isolation using 'find'. Prior to this we might split tests into groups to try to narrow the search space - binary search style - until we got something that worked.

I created a rule in package scripts to do this for me - with some echos to make it more clear what outputs belong to what tests:

```
"find-run-all-tests": "time find . -not -path \"./node_modules/*\" -type f -name \"*.test.js\" -exec echo \\n----------- Testing : {} --------------- \\; -exec node_modules/nodeunit/bin/nodeunit {} \\; -exec echo ----------- Finished : {} --------------- \\; ",
```

This of course allows us to `npm run find-run-all-tests` from the project. This has the benefits that a) it runs the version of nodeunit dictated by the project, b) shows us how much time was spent running the whole suite and c) creates output that clearly implicates which suite was the problem and d) runs each test in complete isolation restarting node each time (big performance penalty here) :

```
tokenoftrust-routes.test.js

✔ test login with basic privileges works.
✔ non-privileged access of privileged page. - when user is not logged in they should be directed to log-in
✖ non-privileged access of privileged page. - when user is logged in they should get an error page

FAILURES: Undone tests (or their setups/teardowns): 
- non-privileged access of privileged page. - when a non-test user is logged in they should STILL be able to see Developer Home

To fix this, make sure all tests call test.done()

----------- Testing : ./website/tests/apiKeysInvite-routes.test.js ---------------
----------- Testing : ./tests/services/requestService.test.js ---------------

requestService.test.js
✔ request service - expire request works.
✔ request service basic CRUD operations on objects work.
✔ request service basic CRUD operations on simple types.

OK: 15 assertions (834ms)
----------- Finished : ./tests/services/requestService.test.js ---------------
```

Again - I don't see us running this all the time bc of the performance cost. In our case it took tests 5x longer to run BUT at a the tiny cost of 4 extra minutes it helped me isolate us isolate a series of problems in a large number of test suites to allow us to skip some of counterproductive sleuthing work we found ourselves doing.

---

This was an odd case where we were forced down this path after some very extensive changes but I want to know if others have/do experience this pain and if so what you're doing to ease the pain/problem. Please do share if I'm missing something obvious or if there's a hack you're using that's saving you gobs of time.

I see this becoming more frequent and expensive as we have more tests so we need to get better and faster.